# Use transient property on any Core Data attribute that doesn't need to be saved?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to understand transient properties.  I have this object:

```
@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *street;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *zip;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```

I use this to show my annotation on a MKMapView.  I want to save these pins in some Route entity.  A Route would just let the user name the route.  For my app, the only thing really important is the latitude and longitude.  The other properties I can always recalculate with a reverse geocoder since I have the lat/long.  To save space, I was thinking that if I want to make this object a Core Data entity, can I make all the properties that are not latitude and longitude transient properties?  I read some examples where transient was used for a prperty that was calculated based on other non-transient properties.  Is this a proper use of transient?  Thanks.

Comment: What sort of "space" are you worried about? Memory or disk space? How many objects do you have? You could be solving a problem that doesn't exist. Note also that transient properties can't be used for fetch requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the case you can apply transient property in your example. From my perspective, you can still keep some properties in the core data to avoid redundant query for later use. For example, the address you can use reverse geocode to get the real address by longitude and latitude. But you will let user to wait for query address every time when you use reverse geocoder. I will prefer to keep the properties in the core data if that property needs a bit of calculation or wait for connection.

Comment: if I store all those values, does it a lot of extra memory you think?

Comment: The most important thing is not to retrieve a lot of records from core data at the same. I will do some profile analysis to make sure the memory I used in normal situation will not cause problem to the iPhone . BTW if your mkmapview move to another region, make sure you remove those annotation not visible map will reduce the memory usage as well.